# Blank screen after google sign-in in react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, webview, google-signin

I'm using "react-native-webview" and source URL (website) uses Google sign-in,  after providing credentials it is showing me a completely blank screen rather than redirecting to the website.

I tried in google chrome for the same website it opens a new popup window and redirect back to the website after the sign-in success

How can I fix it in react native?

Comment: I also have the same issue, did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced a similar problem.

So, aside from implementing onNavigationStateChange inside the WebView, check if your server is redirecting to a URL instead of rendering a page. In my case I had to switch from

```
source={{html: checkoutRes}}
```

to

```
source={{uri: checkoutRes}}
```